# How to convert a single index list into a multi-indexes Python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

in application-1 I save a list (`list_1_app_1`) of *n* elements in a file, this file is later read by application-2.

**application-1**

```
list_1_app_1 = []
def afunction(self):    
    [...]
    self.buildList_1(self.ulx, self.uly, self.brx, self.bry)

def buildList_1(self, ul_x, ul_y, br_x, br_y):
        nrows = br_y - ul_y
        ncols = br_x - ul_x
        self.list_1 = [0 for xx in range(nrows*ncols)]
        global list_1_app_1
        list_1_app_1 = self.list_1
        for i in range(0, nrows):
            for j in range(0, ncols):
                if(i == 0 or i == (nrows -1) or j == 0 or j == (ncols-1)):
                    list_1_app_1[j + i*ncols] = -1
[...]
afunction()
[..]
list_1_file = open('list_1.txt', 'w+')
list_1_file.write(("%s \n" %(list_1_app_1)))
```

in **application-2** I read `list_1.txt`

```
def read_list_1_File(list_file):
    with open(list_file, "r") as ins:
        content = [x.strip() for x in ins]
    return content
list_1_app_2 = read_list_1_File("list_1.txt")
```

In app-1, I copy the list `list_1-app_1[]` to `"list_1.txt"` file

```
#print list_1.txt    
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1,...]
```

so, when I read `"list_1.txt"` in app-2, I get an unidimensional list with all `list_1_app_1[]` elements in `list_1_app_2[0]`.

```
>>>print list_1_app_2    
['[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1,...]']
```

and that is not what I need.
I need `list_1_app_2` to be a (nrows*ncols)-dimensional list, possibly avoiding expensive (nrows*ncols) loops.
Any insight would be very appreciated,

thank you

Comment: Would it be okay to propose to change the save file format?  Or do you have, maybe, hundreds of these already?

Comment: If you want to load the python literal from the file you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this change:

```
for item in list_1_app_1:
  list_1_file.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your only use of the shared file is to save data between your applications, you can use python's own serialization functions from the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module.

Application 1

```
with open('list_1.txt', 'wb') as list_1_file:
    pickle.dump(list_1_app_1, list_1_file)
```

Application 2

```
with open('list_1.txt') as list_1_file:
    list_1_app_2 = pickle.load(list_1_file)
```

Comment: @Alfe Fixed. Wrote it too quick without thinking.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Question already had an open line. Added it into my answer for clarity.  Thanks.